# Alterar uma tabela no banco de dados a partir de uma data em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, eventos

Tenho uma tabela ban_logs que contem uma data e preciso que após essa data, um evento ou trigger seja ativado para alterar o campo is_banned da tabela user_data.

ban_logs
id, user_id, date, until_date;

user_data
user_id, is_banned;

Quando a data for igual ao campo until_date(DATETIME), executar um evento para setar o campo is_banned = 0 where user_id = usuário da tabela ban_logs.

Alguém tem uma dica?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Usando PHP, poderia usar os métodos sub() e diff da classe Datetime(), cada vez que a pagina for carregada as datas são verificadas, dependendo do resultado da verificação, podes aplicar um javascript para dinamizar o trigger

Comment: A ideia é criar um evento, ou adicionar uma data ao evento a partir do until_date para que fosse executado somente quando a data for atingida. Não sei se ficou claro.
Não queria ficar fazendo verificações sempre.